# useEffect is causing an infinite loop but i cant find why. Also what can i improve in the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I made basic blog like project with django rest api and react in frontend but useEffect is causing an infinite loop but i cant find why.I know its the useEffect because it happened few times before while making this project but i was able to fix it but now it has been a bit hard. Also a side question what do u guys think of the code any tip or advice will be appreciated, thanks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
  
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false)
  const [editData, setEditData] = useState([])

  const [create, setCreate] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    completed: false
  })

  const handleCreate = ((e) => {
    const newData = {...create}
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value
    setCreate(newData)
  })


  const handleEdit = ((post) => {
    setCreate({
      title: post.title,
      description: post.description,
    })
    {setEditing(true)}
    {setEditData(post)}
  })

  const handleDelete = ((post) => {
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-delete/${post.id}`, 
      {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
  })
  console.log(post.id)
})

  const handleSubmit = ((e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-create/'

    if (editing == true) {
      url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-update/${editData.id}`
    }
    
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(create)
    })
    .then(setCreate({
      title: "",
      description: "",
      completed: false
    }))
  })

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
    setPosts(await response.json())
  }, [posts])

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7">
            <h1 className="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-light">The Posts</h1>
            {posts.map((post, index) => {
              return(
                <div key={index} class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark mb-1">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                      <p>{post.description}</p>
                      <span class="text-muted">{post.created_at.slice(0, 10)}</span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div className="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
                    <button onClick={() => handleEdit(post)} class="btn btn-outline-warning m-2" type="button">Edit</button>
                    <button onClick={() => handleDelete(post)} class="btn btn-outline-danger m-2" type="button">-</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div> 


        <div className="col-5">
          
          <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} className="mx-2 p-3 rounded border border-2 border-dark">
            <h1 className="p-3 rounded bg-dark text-light">Add New Post</h1>
            
            {/* TITLE */}
            <div style={{ flex: 6 }}>
              <label class="form-label">Title</label>
              <input onChange={(e) =>handleCreate(e)} className="form-control" id="title" value={create.title} type="text" placeholder="Add Post" />
            </div>

            {/* DESCRIPTION */}
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label  class="form-label">Description</label>
              <textarea onChange={(e) =>handleCreate(e)} className="form-control" id="description" value={create.description}  placeholder="Post Description" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>    
            
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark m-3">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        </div> 
      </div>
    )
  }


export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you making `posts` a dependency of your `useEffect`? That is the issue. You update it, it updates the state of `posts`, and the cycle continues over and over. When are you intending the `/api/post-list` request to occur? Just when the component is created? Or when?

Comment: but if i remove posts from useEffect the page wont reload when i update a post is there a work around for that

Comment: theres a lot of things you need to address for this to be a fully proper system. What does the API return when you do an update? (hint it should be the whole entity that was updated). What you should do is not refetch all of the data as that is inefficient as the product scales. You should update the data inside your state to reflect the change. Meaning... if you delete something when the api returns success you also remove that entry from your state. Refetching isn't the correct approach and, as you can probably tell by now, it can cause bugs

Comment: i understand so r u saying me to not refetch all the data but to filter out the deleted post on frontend if thats so what about updated post. can u please give a small example

Answer (score 0):

you are triggering the `useEffect` function when the state `posts` is changed and then proceed to update the state in the `useEffect` function.

better solution:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
    setPosts(await response.json())
  }, [])
```

this will make sure useEffect only runs one time

Comment: but if i remove posts from useEffect the page wont reload when i update a post

Comment: as the render is handled by state you don't need to reload the page for the ui to be updated

Comment: yes when i delete a post or update post i dont want it to show the old post data

Comment: state change will re-render all the components using the state `posts` so the ui will be updated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the posts in dependency array and make it just [].

#### Here what you need to do

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
    setPosts(await response.json())
  }, [])
```

Comment: if i do that i will have to reload after updating or deleting a post to see reaults

Answer (score 0):

The function inside `useEffect` will run every time the value of a dependency is updated.
You added `posts` a dependency of the `useEffect` and updated the value of `posts` inside the effect using `setPosts`.
And it is causing the infinite loop.

Just remove `posts` from the dependency array.

```js
useEffect(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
  setPosts(await response.json())
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
    setPosts(await response.json())
}, [posts])
```

By having `posts` as a dependency, this means that the `useEffect` `callback` will run each time when `posts` gets updated. By updating `posts` in the `callback`, you are causing an infinite loop. To avoid this, you can either remove `posts` from the dependency array.

It is not good to call your API for the whole list each time you add one entry to your list. You have most of the data already loaded, it would be best to do the following in your `handleSubmit` function:

```js
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(create)
    })
    .then(() => {
      setPosts([...posts, create]);
      setCreate({
        title: "",
        description: "",
        completed: false
      });
    })
```

You would append your data from the `create` object, to the already loaded `posts` array.

Answer (score 0):

### This is an infinite loop issue

The problem here is that you trigger the **setPosts** function inside the **useEffect** and you trigger the **useEffect** hook when the value of **posts** change. Since the **setPosts** function, changes the value of **posts**, this is what is causing the loop:

**SetPosts** trigger=> **posts** trigger =>**UseEffect** trigger=> **SetPosts** and the loop continues.

The best way, is to remove posts from the UseEffect hook, or find another dependency for the useEffect hook as shown below;

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
    setPosts(await response.json())
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update posts using setPosts, this executes useEffect() again. The second argument your passing to useEffect tells it to execute your method everytime [posts] updates, so when you call `setPosts(await response.json())` posts updates and your method execute.

You can prevent this with a simple if statement:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    if(posts.length == 0) {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
        setPosts(await response.json())
    }
}, [posts])
```

In the above code the fetch and following setPosts will only execute when the length of the posts array is zero, once you done the fetch and populates posts with 1 or more items then useEffect still gets fired but doesn't do the fetch.

To illustrate this include a second state value `postsFetched` and set this to true once you have fetched posts, this prevents the your method provided use useEffect from executing in the first place. Something like:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [postsFetched, setPostsFetched] = useState(false);
...
useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post-list/')
    setPosts(await response.json())
    // NOTE: you probably want to qualify that you have fetched posts at this point
    setPostsFetched(true);
}, [postsFetched])
```

As my comment in the second snippet says you may want to make sure that you have actually fetched some posts before setting `postsFetched` to true by checking the return from `await response.json()`

Here's some additional reading:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Or you could just leave the useEffect dependency array empty as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

To stop loop, just use [] in UseEffect as others suggestion

Try to use callback and push to add or remove post, this will help getting latest updates.

Eg: postLists.push({title:"a new post", content:"The post content"})

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31996958)